# How to add a windows host usb device to the docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to access the USB device from the Docker container that ran on the Windows host (WSL2). The device is a USB flash drive with the content (files) and serial number. How to mount it and access the data?

I've tried `--device=/dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb` and `usbipd` but it doesn't work.